# is Mage::getModel('my_module')->getCollection()->getData(); ok performance wise?

Tags: magento-1, model, performance

For a homepage I am getting data like this from my module's table:

```
Mage::getModel('my_module')->getCollection()->getData();
```

I wonder if this is the best thing performance wise. There are only 6 rows in that table. Would it be better to load it like this:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++){
    Mage::getModel('my_module')->load($i);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say none of them.

Depending on what you need to achieve I would use collection without loading model and selecting only the attributes you need.

Example: I want to retrieve only name and description of the products with ID: 1,2,3,4,5,6 and 7:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','description'))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)));

foreach ($collection as $product)
{
    echo $product->getName();
    echo $product->getDescription();
}
```

Always try to **avoid loading entire object, especially in a loop.**

Answer (score 2):

Loading a full object like `Mage::getModel('my_module')->load($i)` takes a lot of time.

It is ***always*** a good idea to use the collection model `Mage::getModel('my_module')->getCollection()` instead of loading the full model for better performance.

Collection models always get data from a single query but every call of `load()` makes a new select query, so it's best to use `getCollection()`.

Calling `getData()` at `Mage::getModel('my_module')->getCollection();` is not a good idea. Use for loops for getting data.

And filter the collection by `AddAttributeToFilter()` (for EAV model)
or `AddFiledToFilter()` (for flat table).